# Rsync difference between two directories to a 3rd directory

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

How would I go about rsyncing the difference between two directories to a 3rd directory. For example, if I have the command

> rsync -av --progress --stats /hdd1/ /hdd2/

I would like to copy the difference between hdd1 and hdd2 to a 3rd directory, without copying any data to hdd2 (as it is a full hard drive). What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the `--compare-dest` option of rsync could be helpful.
I think

```
rsync -av --progress --stats --compare-dest=/hdd2 /hdd1/ /3rd_dir/
```

might work.

Comment: I just noticed the compare-dest argument is relative to the '3rd_dir'. In this case you are using absolute path, but if hdd2 where a dir relative to 3rd_dir, you would need to use the relative path from 3rd_dir.