# A tool to compare 2 folders and store the difference?

Tags: diff

Does anybody knows a way to compare 2 versions of a directory to create a 3rd one with the difference of both?

I need it to make incremental updates of my software.

Thx

Comment: You might find [this article](http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html) very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following command

```
$ diff -qr <path_of_folder1> <path_of_folder2>
```

This does an incremental and recursive comparison of both the folders. If you want, you can rsync both the folders to

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/256003/rsync-difference-between-two-directories-to-a-3rd-directory

Comment: basically I will use RSYNC!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php) tool for comparing folders & files

Answer (score 1):

What do your mean with "dfference"?

If you mean patch type difference then use "diff" with "--recursive" flag.

If you mean copying files which are only in second directory or are different in second directory, then it is called "incremental backup". For example use "rsync" with "--backup-dir=DIR" option.

If you need versioning (for software development for instance) then take git (or subversion).